# Progressbar setInterval with remoteCommand

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, progress-bar

I have the following remote command:

```
<p:remoteCommand id="usedCall"
                 name="queryUsed"
                 oncomplete="fetchUsedMemory(#{performanceProvider.queryUsedMemory()})"
                 process="@all" />
```

It calls a bean function and passes the result to the fetchUsedMemory JS function defined in a script block. I want to execute this remoteCommand every 2secs until cancelled and display the result on a ProgressBar. I tried the following:

```
function fetchUsedMemory(usedMemory) {
    var maxValue = jQuery('#TotalMemory').val();

    var pbClient = PF('pbClient');
    var newValue = usedMemory;
    var percentg = (newValue / maxValue) * 100;

    pbClient.setValue(percentg);

    jQuery('#progressText').val('Max: ' + maxValue + ' NEW: ' + newValue + ' %: ' + percentg);
}
```

This function would have updated the progressbar and an inputText to verify the results. Then the function that starts the whole process:

```
function start() {
    PF('startButton1').disable();
    PF('cancelButton1').enable();
    window['progress'] = setInterval(queryUsed, 1000);
}
```

I tried to pass in here the name of the remoteCommand, but it only gets called **once**. No further calls are being done towards the bean. Finally here's my HTML:

```
    <p:panel id="mProgressPanel">

        <p:progressBar id="progressBar" widgetVar="pbClient" style="width: 500px;" />
        <p:inputText id="progressText" style="display: block; width: 1000px;" />

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton id="StartProgress" disabled="true"
                             type="button" onclick="start()"
                             value="Start"
                             widgetVar="startButton1" />
            <p:commandButton id="StopProgress" disabled="true"
                             type="button" onblur="cancel()"
                             value="Stop"
                             widgetVar="cancelButton1"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panel>
```

Is there a way to make it work so that the setInterval calls the remoteCommand correctly? Thanks for your helps!

Comment: You do realize that `#{performanceProvider.queryUsedMemory()}` would be evaluated only one time, the oncomplete is merely javascript function and the passed parameter is not going to change each time the oncomplete is going to be executed.

Comment: That I already know. That's the reason I asked how can I make it work, and not why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<p:poll>`, here's an idea

*xhtml*

```
<p:poll interval="2" listener="#{performanceProvider.queryUsedMemory()}" 
        oncomplete ="updateMemory(xhr, status, args)" widgetVar="pollWV"
        process="@this" />
```

*ManagedBean*

```
public void queryUsedMemory() {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("memory", getUsedMemory() + 10);
}
```

*javascript*

```
function updateMemory(xhr, status, args) {
   if(args.memory) {
      //update what ever you want

      //Stop polling if the memory is 100
      if(args.memory === 100) {
         PF('pollWV').stop();
      }
   }
}
```